# C# Null Coalescing Operator Behaves Differently in Conjunction with OR Operator Between Null and Empty Collection

Tags: c#

I've observed some odd behaviour with the null coalescing operator in conjunction with the OR operator and wondered if anybody could shed some light this.

```
var nullCollection = null as IEnumerable<string>;
var emptyCollection = Enumerable.Empty<string>();

Console.WriteLine(nullCollection?.Any() ?? false || true);
Console.WriteLine(emptyCollection?.Any() ?? false || true);
```

Yields the following output:

```
True
False
```

Simply evaluating `nullCollection?.Any() ?? false` or `emptyCollection?.Any() ?? false` both yield `False`, which would be the expected behaviour, but combining the condition with the `||` operator seems to cause the second condition to not be evaluated, but only in cases where the collection is empty.

Adding some additional parenthesis to the null coalescing condition seems to solve the problem:

```
Console.WriteLine((nullCollection?.Any() ?? false) || true);
Console.WriteLine((emptyCollection?.Any() ?? false) || true);
```

Yielding:

```
True
True
```

Why is this? What's going on here? What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [operators precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence), conditional OR operator `||` has higher priority than null-coalescing operator `??`.

According to [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) specs:

> The `??` operator doesn't evaluate its right-hand operand if the
>   left-hand operand evaluates to non-null.

So, in your code adding a parenthesis is needed to make the correct order of execution and `??` operator evaluation.

Without parenthesis this `nullCollection?.Any()` returns `null`, therefore `??` operator returns result of `false || true` (because of priority, mentioned above), which is always `true`.

`emptyCollection?.Any()` result is not `null` and returns `false`, therefore right side `false || true` isn't evaluated, compiler is smart enough to understand it.

Adding a parenthesis force the compiler to perform the expected execution of operators:

- `(nullCollection?.Any() ?? false)` returns `false` because left-side
  operand is `null` and right side operand is executed.
- `(emptyCollection?.Any() ?? false)` also returns `false`, left-side
  operand isn't `null` and right side isn't executed.

Logical OR for `false || true` returns `true` in both cases and you'll see a desired behavior

Comment: If that was the case it should evaluate to true, but it's evaluating to false.

Comment: @JamesLaw `emptyCollection?.Any()` returns `false`, the right side of `??` operator isn't evaluated, I've updated an answer

Comment: Thanks, your answer makes much more sense now.

Comment: Just one more thing, if the OR operator is of higher precedence than the null-coalescing operator, surely the OR should be evaluated first? It appears that the null-coalescing operator is evaluated ahead of the OR despite the precedence - why is this?

Comment: Would you be so kind as to update the first sentence of your answer to make this clear please? (I feel stating that it's an operator precedence issue as opposed to operator associativity issue is misleading as in fact the null-coalescing operator is evaluated first in this situation and the OR is never evaluated as it's considered the result of a null null-coalescing evaluation.)

Comment: @JamesLaw I've deleted a comment, associativity isn't a point here. `??` operator evaluates the right side only when left side is null. In second example `emptyCollection?.Any()` right side is never executed. In first sample right side is executed, `||` has higher priority and `false || true` is executed as right side. Adding a parenthesis forces right side to return `false` first, and then logical OR with `true`

Comment: So why does the null-coalescing operator execute first when the OR operator takes precedence over it?

Comment: @JamesLaw The order of execution is correct, all operators are evaluated from left to right, according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operand-evaluation). Without parenthesis right side of this `emptyCollection?.Any()` is never executed, adding them will evaluate `false || true`. In first snippet `false || true` is evaluated before `??` evaluates left side in gets `null`

Answer (score 2):

The Conditional OR operator has a higher precedence than the Null-coalescing operator, as explained [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence).

This means that in both your lines of code, `false || true` is computed to be always true.

Therefore, the compiler effectively does this:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(nullCollection?.Any() ?? true);
Console.WriteLine(emptyCollection?.Any() ?? true);
```

In the first line the result is null, so we use the null-coalesce and print `True` instead.

In the second line, the result is non-null - it is `False` as the collection is empty - so `False` is printed.

Comment: But false || true is true?

Answer (score 1):

**For the null collection:**

`nullCollection?.Any()` is `null`, so you're evaluating `null ?? false || true`.

The operator precedence rules means that || is evaluated first:

`null ?? (false || true)`, which simplifies to  `null ?? true`, which then resolves to `true`.

**For the empty collection:**

Since `emptyCollection?.Any()` returns `false`, it is not null and the coalesce is not performed.

Conceptually, 
`emptyCollection?.Any() ?? (false || true)`, is equivalent to `false ?? (false || true)` or `false ?? true`, so it will resolve to `false`.

*(of course this does not actually compile as `bool` is not a nullable type)*

Comment: But it doesn't resolve to true, it resolves to false when the collection is empty.

Comment: Answer updated for empty collection case - null coalesce right-operand not called when the left-operand is non-null